# Find the point on the curve where the tangent line is orthogonal to the plane.

Tags: calculus

Find the point on the curve $$ \overrightarrow{\rm r}(t) = \langle t^3+3t, t^2+1, \ln (1+2t) \rangle  ,   0\leq t \leq \pi$$ where the tangent line is orthogonal to the plane $$15x+4y+0.4z=10$$.

So I was able to find the derivative: $$\overrightarrow{\rm r}'(t) = (3t^2+3)\overrightarrow{\rm i} + 2t\overrightarrow{\rm j} +(2\div(1+2t))\overrightarrow{\rm k} $$

and the normal vector to the plane: $$\overrightarrow{\rm n}=\langle 15,4,0.4\rangle$$

I attempted to solve by finding the dot product of the $\overrightarrow{\rm r}'(t)$ and the $\overrightarrow{\rm n}$ and I got $ t=-0.507614$

This doesn't work out when I plug it back in. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that the way you solved for $t$ was by setting $\vec r'\cdot\vec n=0$. This equation says that $\vec r'$ is orthogonal to $\vec n$, but that makes it *parallel* to a plane with normal $\vec n$, not orthogonal to it. What you want is for $\vec r'$ to be parallel to $\vec n$, that is $\vec r'=\lambda \vec n$ for some nonzero scalar $\lambda$. Since you’re working in $\mathbb R^3$, you can avoid introducing an extra variable by using the equivalent condition $\vec r'\times\vec n=0$. This will give you a system of three equations in $t$ to solve.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\overrightarrow{\rm r}'(t) = (3t^2+3)\overrightarrow{\rm i} + 2t\overrightarrow{\rm j} +(\color{red}2\div(1+2t))\overrightarrow{\rm k}$$

As noticed by amd in the comments, of course we need to find t by the condition

$$\vec r'(t) \times \vec n=\vec 0$$

Comment: Thank you! I edited it!

Comment: $\vec r'\cdot\vec n=0$ says that $\vec r'$ is parallel to the plane, not that it’s orthogonal to it.

Comment: @amd OMG! Thanks...that’s a nice consideration! I fix that!

Comment: That was the fundamental error made by the OP.

Comment: @amd Yes of course I didn’t though sufficiently about that, since I’ve recognized a mistake in the derivative which probably was only a typo and assuming as correct all the derivation! That’s not good of course. Thanks again for the advice! Bye

Answer (score 0):

The derivative should be $\overrightarrow{\rm r}'(t) = (3t^2+3)\overrightarrow{\rm i} + 2t\overrightarrow{\rm j} +(2\div(1+2t))\overrightarrow{\rm k}\\$
. The kth direction should have a 2 in numerator. Now all you do is equate the norm to this derivative to ensure they have the same direction (then tangent is perpendicular to plane) should give you $t=2$ then plug this in for your equation of the plane.

Comment: When you say equate it, do you mean that $\overrightarrow{\rm r}'(t)$ should equal the $\overrightarrow{\rm n}(t)$? and finding dot product isn't necessary?

Comment: Thank you for the correction for nth direction!

Answer (score 0):

$r = t^3+3t,t^2+1,\ln(1+2t)\\
\frac {dr}{dt} = 3t^2 + 3, 2t, \frac {2}{2t + 1}$

If $\frac {dr}{dt}$ is normal to your plane.

$\frac {dr}{dt}$ points in the same direction as $(15,4,0.4)$
or for some $\lambda, \frac {dr}{dt} = \lambda (15,4,0.4)$

At this point, by inspection we see that at $t = 2$

$\frac {dr}{dt} = (15,4,0.4)$

If we were not so lucky, and we wanted to use the dot product.

then $\frac {dr}{dt}\cdot (15,4,0.4) = \|\frac {dr}{dt}\|\|(15,4,0.4)|$

but $\|\frac {dr}{dt}\| = \sqrt{9t^4 + 22t^2 + 9 + \frac {4}{4t^2 + 4t + 1}}$

looks like a mess to work with.

If it were something nicer, I am still not sure I would use that formula.

I might say:
$T = \frac {\frac {dr}{dt}}{\|\frac {dr}{dt}\|}$ is the unit tangent vector.

$\frac {dT}{dt}$ is normal to $T.$  and hence in your plane when T takes on the correct direction and

$\frac {dT}{dt} \cdot (15,4, 0.4) = 0$